# how to get the response of json in ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
{
    "status": {
        "imsg": "Cannot create alignment that already exists",
        "emsg": "Unable to serve your request",
        "category": "Conflict",
        "code": 409
    },
    "resources": [{
        "data": {
            "match_code": "I",
            "standard": {
                "guid": "A44D16E2-8386-11E1-9D3E-8F3A9DFF4B22"
            },
            "self": "http://api.academicbenchmarks.com/rest/v3/standards/A44D16E2-8386-11E1-9D3E-8F3A9DFF4B22/assets
/1351AE36-4B61-11E0-8B12-F25B9DFF4B22",
            "label": "Include",
            "asset": {
                "guid": "1351AE36-4B61-11E0-8B12-F25B9DFF4B22"
            }
        }
    }],
    "count": 1,
    "type": "alignment"
}
```

i want to get the status of "emsg" and "resources" data

Any one suggest to get the results

Am using below code to receive in ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: apicall,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { 
                      alert(data);

        }
    });
```

Comment: its difficult to understand  your question

Comment: i got response from API like json data. i want use the json data to get the message in ajax success

Comment: JSON.parse is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSON.parse to decode your JSON from server.Something like this.

```
var b='{"status":{"imsg": "Cannot create alignment that already exists", "emsg": "Unable to serve your request", "category": "Conflict", "code": 409}, "resources": [{"data":{"match_code": "I", "standard":{"guid": "A44D16E2-8386-11E1-9D3E-8F3A9DFF4B22"}, "self": "http://api.academicbenchmarks.com/rest/v3/standards/A44D16E2-8386-11E1-9D3E-8F3A9DFF4B22/assets/1351AE36-4B61-11E0-8B12-F25B9DFF4B22", "label": "Include", "asset":{"guid": "1351AE36-4B61-11E0-8B12-F25B9DFF4B22"}}}], "count": 1, "type": "alignment"}';

var b1=JSON.parse(b);
console.log(b1);
console.log(b1['status']['emsg']);
console.log(b1['resources']);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d5xzexw9/6/

Access values like so,

```
var b1=JSON.parse(b); 
var em=b1['status']['emsg']; 
var label1=b1['resources']["0"]["data"]["label"]; //AND SO ON...
```

Comment: thanks, how to get the total response in a variable in jquery ajax

Comment: @MohankumarV Total response as in ,do you need each and every value revieved or any particular fields?

Comment: Something like this,`var b1=JSON.parse(b);`

`var em=b1['status']['emsg'];

var label1=b1['resources']["0"]["data"]["label"];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data.status.emsg //to get value of emsg and 
data.resources //to get resources.
```

Data.resources will return you an array

Comment: am not getting the alert inside of success

Comment: Might be then function is not coming into success ... add an onerror block and check

Comment: yes this with the error message, now i got my result ,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: apicall,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { 
         alert(data.status.emsg);
        }
    });
```